# Python twisted forward http post body to tcp port

Tags: python, twisted

I have an echo server running in localhost at port 9999. I am developing a web server using twisted ( I am new to twisted and python in general). The client will stream the data using chunked encoding with HTTP. What I want the server to do is to send this data to port 9999 and get the response from there and write back as http response. But I even can't make the sending part work. This is what i have done till now.

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory

class Clientp(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, req):
        self.req = req

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.writeSequence(self.req.content.read())

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print ("+ got reply" + str(data))
        # I have to send the data via resposne here

class Counter(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_POST(self, request):
        def clientProtocol():
            return Clientp(request)
        endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "127.0.0.1", 9999)
        endpoint.connect(Factory.forProtocol(clientProtocol))
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET

endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:8000").listen(server.Site(Counter()))
reactor.run()
```

I can't write the post content (`request.content.read()`) to the TCP endpoint. I'm getting `TypeError("Data must be bytes")` error. Any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> def connectionMade(self):
>     self.transport.writeSequence(self.req.content.read())
> ```

[ITransport.writeSequence](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.html#writeSequence) accepts an iterable of bytes.  [IRequest](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.web.iweb.IRequest.html#content).content.read returns a bytes object.

You get the error `TypeError("Data must be bytes")` because *iterating* over bytes in Python 3 results in integers.  It is these integers that the implementation is complaining about.

You should just use [ITransport.write](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.html#write), instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Even if i use `ITransport.write`, the `self.req.content.read()` value is not received by the echoserver. Is there any other issues with the code?

Comment: As the request data from the http client is chunked, it should be streamed to echo server. Is this the correct method? pardon me because I'm new to twisted

Comment: How do you know it isn't received by the echo server?

Comment: I am doing a `print` on the echo server. If I add `self.transport.write('test string'.encode("utf-8")`, it is getting passed through, but not `self.transport.write(self.req.content.read())`. Data is not even getting  if I am not using chunked encoding.

Comment: I suggest you add those details to a new question.  I think this one is answered.  SO is not well suited to chat-style interactions.